# Oracle Query Error ORA-00933 SQL Command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to run a simple inner join in a query on a 5.1 Oracle Database.

```
SELECT
    W.ID,
    WE.CLASS
FROM
    W
INNER JOIN
    WE
    ON (W.ID=WO.ID)
WHERE
    WO.ID='688158'
```

It results in the Command not properly ended.

I can do

```
Select
    W.ID, WE.CLASS from W, WE
WHERE
    W.ID=WO.ID and WO.ID='688158'
```

and it doesn't error out but doesn't return the results I want because of the lack of join.

Thanks!

Comment: Oracle 5.1 was released in 1986 and I highly doubt you are using that. Which Oracle version are you ***really*** using? What is the output of `select * from v$version`?

Comment: 8.0.5.2.1.  I was mixed up the version of CMMS that is using the oracle back end with the oracle version.

Comment: Oracle 8.0 is also long dead and forgotten - it does not support the explicit `JOIN` operator. But the two statements are logically equivalent, they just use a different style of joining. But neither of them will work because you are referencing an alias (or table) `wo` that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your table name is used incorrectly. Should be:

```
SELECT
    W.ID,
    WE.CLASS
FROM
    W
INNER JOIN
    WE
    ON (W.ID = WE.ID)
WHERE
    WE.ID='688158';
```

`WE` instead of `WO`

Comment: Thank you.  When I was typing this in last night I was tired after working on this for most of the day and actually had my query like you edited.  I apologize.  I have Select W.ID, WE.CLASS FROM W INNER JOIN WE ON (W.ID=WE.ID) where WE.ID='688158'